# Social sharing for specific assets

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, share

I am developing an analytical app using NodeJS and Express and I would like to give the user the option to share the currently filtered graph along with a title and a sample description. I would like to have an option to share to Facebook, Twitter and Google +. I have done some research and I have managed to find a few libraries that were supposed to suite me. One of which was `social-share` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/social-share). The problem with this library is that I was unable to upload images to Facebook or Twitter, as well as the missing Google+ option.
The other library I have found is `twit` (https://github.com/ttezel/twit) which I still have not tried but either way it is for Twitter only.

After some time of trying to find a trivial solution, I started looking into the "build my own" option. I registered my app in the Facebook Developers console. I followed all the steps there to setup the SDK and the smple share code. The problem there was that the URL I wanted to share (http://127.0.0.1:3000/ or localhost at my case) was not "in the allowed domains for the application". I have tried a number if solutions for this error but none seemed to work. I have creadet a "Test app" under the original app in Facebook Dev Console. I have also tried creating an entirely new application for purely development purposes. (Note: in both previously stated caces I have switched the app ids obviously). I also tried the settings options for "Add platform" with "localhost" as the site URL. I have tried adding it as allowed domains and other options but I could not seem to get it to work.

What I also tried was the "Add This" option to share, leveraging the meta og: tags for image. The content is dynamically generated so I figured I should update the contents of the meta tags dynamically as well (using jQuery in my case). The problem I see there is the following: Facebook scrapes the page periodically and therefore the dynamic content from the og: tags is not fetched. Also the share button always used the information scraped from the `url` that I tried to share.

So after all this my questions are: Is there a trivial way in which I can have simple share buttons which the user can share the currently visible content (Highcharts graph) along with a title and text (prefilled by the app)? Is this supported for Facebook, Twitter and Google +?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to specify any of those values dynamically/at runtime any more; all the info is taken from the OG meta data the URL returns only. If you want to share individual combinations of content - then you have to create individual URLs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply CBroe. So basically what you are saying is that there is no option whatsoever to share dynamic content? When I generate a graph (or other canvas element) the user cannot share it?

Comment: I just told you what the option for that is.

Comment: Sorry I did not quite understand that. So if I get the share button to open a new window with generated HTML content (including new og: tags) with some random unique string as url and the graph image and other details and have the user share that url it will work? Will Facebook scrape the newly generated og meta info?

Comment: _"Will Facebook scrape the newly generated og meta info?"_ - why would it not? It does so for any other URL you share, so why would there be anything special about this case now?

Comment: True, but I have noticed that it scrapes the content periodically. So that got  me thinking if it will scrape the newly created page instantly.

Comment: Of course it does, it will do so for every URL that is shared for the first time.

Comment: That is fine but how about other social media platforms such as Twitter and Google+?

Comment: Go read their documentation and find out ...?